# Bash is automatically reloading (injecting) updates into a running script upon saving it: Why? Any practical use?

Tags: bash, shell, scripting

I was writing a bash script, and happened to updated the code (saved the script file to disk) while the script was waiting for some input in a `while` loop. After I returned to the terminal and continued with the previous invocation of the script, bash gave an error about the file syntax:

```
/home/aularon/bin/script: line 58: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `"'
/home/aularon/bin/script: line 67: syntax error: unexpected end of file
```

So I tried doing the following:

**1st:** create a script, `self-update.sh` let's call it:

```
#!/bin/bash
fname=$(mktemp)
cat $0 | sed 's/BEFORE\./AFTER!./' > $fname
cp $fname $0
rm -f $fname
echo 'String: BEFORE.';
```

What the script does is reading its code, changing the word 'BEFORE' into 'AFTER', then re-write itself with the new code.

**2nd** Run it:

```
chmod +x self-update.sh
./self-update.sh
```

**3rd** wonder...

```
aularon@aularon-laptop:~$ ./self-update.sh 
String: AFTER!.
```

Now, I wouldn't have guessed that on the same invocation it would output *AFTER!*, on the second run for sure, but not on the first one.

So my question is: is it intentional (by design)? or it is because of the way bash runs the script? Line by line or command by command. Is there any good use of such behaviour? Any example of it?

---

**Edit:** I tried reformatting the file to put all command in one line, it does not work now:

```
#!/bin/bash
fname=$(mktemp);cat $0 | sed 's/BEFORE\./AFTER!./' > $fname;cp $fname $0;rm -f $fname;echo 'String: BEFORE.';
```

Output:

```
aularon@aularon-laptop:~$ ./self-update.sh #First invocation
String: BEFORE.
aularon@aularon-laptop:~$ ./self-update.sh #Second invocation
String: AFTER!.
```

While when moving the `echo` string to the next line, separating it from the rewriting (`cp`) call:

```
#!/bin/bash
fname=$(mktemp);cat $0 | sed 's/BEFORE\./AFTER!./' > $fname;cp $fname $0;rm -f $fname;
echo 'String: BEFORE.';
```

And now it works again:

```
aularon@aularon-laptop:~$ ./self-update.sh 
String: AFTER!.
```

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4754592/could-replacing-a-bash-script-with-a-new-version-cause-a-running-instance-of-the

Comment: I've looked through the source, but I can't really find any explanation for this. I'm pretty sure though that I've seen some self-extracting installers that were implemented as shell scripts a few years ago. These scripts contains some lines of executable shell commands, and then a huge data block that is read by these commands. So I'll assume that this is designed this way so that bash doesn't have to read the whole script into memory which wouldn't work with huge self-extracting scripts.

Comment: Here's an example of an SFX script: http://ftp.games.skynet.be/pub/wolfenstein/et-linux-2.56-update.x86.run

Comment: Nice! I remember seeing these self installing scripts, AMD Catalyst driver (proprietary) still ships like this, it self-extracts and then installs. These **depend** on such behaviour of reading the files in chunks. Thanks for the example!

Answer (score 16):

This is by design. Bash reads scripts in chunks. So it'll read a portion of the script, run any lines that it can, and then read the next chunk.

So you run into something like this:

- Bash reads the first 256 bytes (bytes 0-255) of the script.
- Within that first 256 bytes is a command that takes a while to run, and bash starts that command, waiting for it to exit.
- While the command is running, the script is updated, and the portion changed is **after** the 256 bytes it already read.
- When the command bash was running finishes, it continues reading the file, resuming from where it was, getting bytes 256-511.
- That portion of the script changed, but bash doesn't know that.

Where this becomes even more problematic is that if you edit anything before byte 256. Lets say you delete a couple of lines. Then the data in the script that was at byte 256, is now somewhere else, say at byte 156 (100 bytes earlier). Because of this, when bash continues reading, it's going to get what was originally 356.

*This is just an example. Bash doesn't necessarily read 256 bytes at a time. I don't know exactly how much it reads at a time, but it doesn't matter, behavior is still the same.*

Comment: No, it reads by chunks, but rewinds to where it was to be sure to read the next command as it is after the previous command has returned.

Comment: @StephaneChazelas Where are you getting that from? I just did an strace and it doesn't so much as even `stat` the file to see if it's changed. No `lseek` calls.

Comment: See http://pastie.org/8662761 for the relevant parts of the strace output. See how the `echo foo` changed to a `echo bar` during the `sleep`. It's been behaving like that for as far back as versions 2, so I don't think it's a version issue.

Comment: Apparently it reads the file line by line, I tried with the file and that what I found out. I will edit my question to highlight that behaviour.

Comment: @Patrick if you can update your answer to reflect it is reading line by line, so I can accept your answer. (Check my edit to the question on that matter).

Comment: @StephaneChazelas You're getting that because you're running an external command. When bash runs an external command it does seem to re-read the script from the end of the last line it executed. If you remove your sleep and do a `read foo` instead (to make it pause. `read` is a shell builtin, it doesn't have to call anything for it), you'll see the difference.

Comment: You're right, though, it seems to be more the _fork_ than the _external command_ that triggers the rewind. `(read foo)` also triggers a rewind. I suppose the rationale is that if ever the command that is _spawned_ wants to read from the script it reads it from the correct position (think for instead of `bash < file` case where `file` has `head -n3 > x`, 3 more lines, and `some other command`). The fact that it doesn't do it for builtins looks like an oversight (`read` could be used to read from the script).